# Why Kubernetes HPA convert custom metric?

Tags: kubernetes

Kubernetes Horisontal Pod Autoscaling (HPA) modifies my custom metric: StackDriver displays correct metric, but HPA shows another number. 
For example, StackDrives value is 118K, but HPA displays 1656144. 
I understand that HPA use some conversation for floating numbers, but my metric is integer: Unit: number Kind: Gauge Value type: Int64.

Running in GKE 1.11.7.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Vitaly, could you share your HPA manifest? Default HPA is implemented as **control loop**, controlled by the controller manager’s --horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period flag. Thoses metrics might depends on some fields like `targetAverageValue` or `targetAverageUtilization` which have influence for **HPA Algorithm**. Here is general information https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#how-does-the-horizontal-pod-autoscaler-work
Please upload your HPA manifest.

Comment: Sure: 

   apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta1
   kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler 
   metadata:
     name: myhpa
     namespace: default
   spec:
     scaleTargetRef:
       apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
       kind: Deployment
       name: mydeploy
     minReplicas: 1
     maxReplicas: 10
     metrics:
     - type: External
       external:
         metricName: custom.googleapis.com|rabbit_q_size
         targetValue: 10000

Answer (score 0):

if you specify `targetValue` it will be a whole number, so there won't be scaling down of pods. 
If you use `targetAverageValue` it will calculate based on the number of pods created.

Answer (score 0):

In your HPA manifest you did not specify value of `--horizontal-pod-autoscaler-sync-period` flag. As default it is set to 15 seconds.

In your case it means that HPA value is amout of whole deployment queue in last 15 seconds. More information can be found in [HPA Documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#how-does-the-horizontal-pod-autoscaler-work).

As you mentioned in StackDriver you used **GAUGE** metric which measures a value at a particular point in time - [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/management-tools/stackdriver-tips-and-tricks-understanding-metrics-and-building-charts)

In short, StackDriver shows current value in the exact time, HPA values is amount of last 15 seconds.

Comment: >HPA values is amount of last 15 seconds
I'm not sure I understand you.

Comment: Your HPA gather information from whole deployment. As TargetValue is 10000, HPA will create another pod when RabbitMQ queue will reach this value.
The Value of HPA will be sum of all messages from all pods received for last 15 seconds. Thats why StackDriver had 118k messages in the moment when you checked value, however HPA had 1,6 mln because it sum amount of all deployment messages from last 15 seconds.

Comment: I don't think so. In my case, I used a custom metric from the standalone RabbitMQ server.